# ASP drop down select showing up weird

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been trying to create a drop down list with asp tag helpers and for some reason they always look strange. I'll include my code for Controller, View, and view model. Also the picture of how it looks.
Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var dalias = await _context.DeptAliases
        .Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Alias, Value = m.DeptAliasPkey.ToString() }).Distinct()
        .ToListAsync();

        var vm = new CopyCenterCreateViewModel()
        {
            DAlias = dalias, 
        };
        return View(vm);
}
```

View:

```
@model PrintShop.ViewModels.CopyCenterCreateViewModel
<form  asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <label asp-for="DAlias" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="DAlias" asp-items="Model.DAlias" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="DAlias" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CopyCenterCreateViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> DAlias { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image: image of dropdown]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "look strange" here.  To "someone" it may be a thing of beauty but we can only guess at present.

Comment: Please include your CSS since that is/will also play into what you see here.

Comment: What do you want,multiple select or single select?If you want multiple select,it is the default style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `select` control is rendering in multi-selection mode. If the tag helper `asp-for` is binding to an `IEnumerable` then the `select` element is rendered in multiple mode.

From [tag-helpers multiple select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#multiple-select) section of the docs:

> The Select Tag Helper will automatically generate the `multiple = "multiple"` attribute if the property specified in the asp-for
> attribute is an `IEnumerable`.

You only have a single property in the ViewModel which is a `List`, and you're binding the items to the same property as the selected value.

You could rename the list of items to something else and add a property to bind to the value of the selected item:

```
public class CopyCenterCreateViewModel
{
    public string DAlias { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller you'd populate the `Items` property of the `CopyCenterCreateViewModel`.

In the view bind `asp-items` to the view model `Items` property:

```
<select asp-for="DAlias" asp-items="Model.Items" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: This worked, I had no idea that there was even an option for it to bind to multiple. Thanks a million!